# Will embedded Google custom search have any impacts on page ranking?

Tags: google-search, pagerank

I would like to embed the Google custom search box into my website as most websites do, since it could provide full text search. Just wondering if this in use or not could have any impacts on page ranking?

Answer (score 0):

Page rank wont change in anyway by embedded  Google custom search .

Comment: any references for this?